# Capacity of two channels in series

Tags: information-theory

Consider two discrete memoryless channels with capacities $C_1$ and $C_2$. We have them cascaded in series i.e., the output of the Channel-1 (capacity $C_1$) is fed as input to Channel-2 (capacity $C_2$). Let $C$ be the overall capacity of this serial setup.

Is it true that $C \leq \min(C_1,C_2)$? Intuitively it appears true. I am looking for a formal proof.

As a follow-up can it be shown that $C = \min(C_1,C_2)$?

Thank you!

Comment: What did you try, and where are you stuck?

Comment: BTW two channels in series is ambiguous - do we have decoders and encoders between the two channels, or is the output of one channel fed directly into the input of the second? This matters for the lower bound.

Answer (score 0):

If the channels are combined in series, the random variables they transition form a markov chain, $X\stackrel{C_1}{-}Y\stackrel{C_2}{-}Z$. The first result can then be obtained using the data processing inequality.

For every input distribution $p_X$, we would have $I(X; Z) \leq I(X; Y)$ and $I(X; Z) \leq I(Y; Z)$
\begin{align*}
C &= \max_{p_X} I(X; Z) \leq \max_{p_X} I(X; Y) = C_1\\
C&= \max_{p_X} I(X; Z) \leq \max_{p_X} I(Y; Z) \leq \max_{p_Y} I(Y; Z) = C_2
\end{align*}
Where the last inequality occurs because the set of $p_Y$ which can be obtained through $p_Y(y) = \sum_x p(y|x) p_X(x)$ is a subset of the set of all probability distributions $p_Y$ on $Y$.

The second result is not true in general. As a counterexample, consider two $BSC(p)$ channels in series. They form a $BSC(2p(1-p))$ channel when combined.